# kill -9 is the last resort when killing a process. What is the first resort?

Tags: linux, kill-process

## Preface

I am asking this question since it falls under the [Coding Techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) aspect of asking questions.

## Background

For a while, whenever I did not know how to kill a process, I would use [`kill`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html) [`-9`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Signal-specifications.html#Signal-specifications) by default.  However, I have been told that this is the option of last resort, since -9 cannot be ignored according to the signal specifications:

> ‘KILL’
>
> 9. Kill (cannot be caught or ignored).

## Attempted methods

In the past, I have also tried the following methods

1. Ctrl-C (or the [SIGINT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGINT) signal).
2. Ctrl-Z (or the the [SIGTSTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_(Unix)#Implementation) signal), followed by a [`ps`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) -ef | grep username, then a kill -9 of the process.

## Question

From a coding technique perspective, what is the first resort when killing a process?

Comment: `SIGTERM` followed by `SIGKILL` if needed https://major.io/2010/03/18/sigterm-vs-sigkill/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kill -TERM` tells the process to terminate itself.  Most applications have a handler to detect this and will cleanup themselves properly so the next run doesn't deal with artifacts from the previous run.  This is also mapped to 15 on UNIX/Linux systems.

Comment: This is also the default if you just `kill 1234`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use SIGQUIT which can be sent by pressing `Ctrl + \`. This also generates a core dump, which can be analysed.

SIGQUIT is mapped to signal number 3. So its same as `kill -3 pid`.